# Meaning of <!cfmodule/> in coldFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Somebody know what is mean
expresion like this:

```
<!cfmodule template="/backend/_modules/_sendDeclinedEmailNotice.cfm">
```

Actually I don't know what means ! in this line.

Comment: how is this not a real question and how is it difficult to tell what is being asked? it is 100% obvious what is being asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything. That will just keep the tag from being interpreted by ColdFusion. If you place that on a page, and then view in the browser, you'll see the actualy `<!cfmodule` text in the browser. Someone apparently just added an exclamation point to keep the module from running, instead of properly commenting it out.